# Usando Javascript (Confirm) dentro de arquivo .php (formulário de alteração de cadastro)

Tags: php, sql

Estou criando um sistema de login e cadastro de usuários com PHP e SQL, porém estou tendo um certo problema ao usar um confirm para confirmar as alterações feitas, se eu clico em "OK" ele executa normalmente a tarefa que designei, mas se eu clico em cancelar ele executa a mesma tarefa, independente se eu cliquei em confirmar ou cancelar, se alguém puder me dar uma luz por favor ficaria agradecido.
(OBSERVAÇÃO: OS ALERT SÃO APENAS PARA TESTAR SE AS AÇÕES ESTÃO FUNCIONANDO CORRETAMENTE DE ACORDO COM O VALOR RETORNADO PELO CONFIRM, QUE É JUSTAMENTE ONDE ESTÁ DANDO PROBLEMA)

```
<html>
<?php

include_once("conexao.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];
//
$nome = $_POST['usuario'];
//
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
//
$setor = $_POST['setor'];
//
$nasc = $_POST['data'];
//


echo '<script type="text/JavaScript"> confirm("Tem certeza que deseja alterar o cadastro ?"); {

if (false) {
  alert("Alterações descartadas !").break;
}

else {
  alert("Alterações realizadas com sucesso !");
}} </script>';

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
</html>
```

Comment: Onde está `if (false)` faça `if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja alterar o cadastro ?"))` mas tem um problema muito maior com o seu código. Da maneira que escreveu a linha `mysqli_close($mysqli);` é nítido que espera trabalhar com javascript e php simultaneamente. Isso não ocorre. o fluxo de processamento de  aplicações cliente servidor é peculiar.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo ! Sei que existem muitos erros nesse meu código, mas de fato não é um trabalho comercial, não vou nem chegar a colocar no ar esse sistema, estou fazendo mesmo como estudo, como aprendizado, e muito obrigado pelo aprendizado, estou em fase de estudo e toda e qualquer informação é de extrema importância no meu caso que ainda estou em 0,1% de evolução em programação geral, mas conheço um pouco sobre cada linguagem (HTML, PHP, CSS, JAVA e SQL).

Comment: O problema é que outras pessoas ao longo do tempo, com diferentes graus de conhecimento, irão ler essa página alguns tentarão implementar o que está aqui(como já ocorreu em outras postagens) e depois vem reclamar sobre perdas e prejuízos.

Comment: Para a finalidade do site é importante você [edit] a pergunta e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Sobre uso de alert, não é um bom teste, pois as mensagens aparecerão em um mometo distinto de quando ocorreu de fato a geração do HTML, confundindo mais ainda o entendimento.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** Se é para aprender a função ok. Mas se for realizar o desenvolvimento para o mercado, tem que mudar tudo. Primeiro realizar a separação entre os arquivos do script, fazendo com que os eventos sejam gerenciados pelo javascript realizando o envio via ajax dos dados para o arquivo php que realizar as ações de edição e interação com o banco e retornará o resultado para o arquivo javascript que realizará a ação de informar o resultado na página do usuário. São três pontos: Interface de interação do usuário, Gerenciamento dos eventos e Gestão do modelo de negócio da aplicação.

**Correção do erro apresentado na estruturação do confirm();**

Passei a reposta de retorno do `confirm()` para uma variável, depois realizei a operação relacional com if e else, em seguida exibir a mensagem na função `Alert()` de acordo com o resultado.

```
echo '
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        let mensagem;
        let retorno = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja alterar o cadastro ?");
        if (retorno == false) {
            mensagem = "Alterações descartadas!";
        } else {
            mensagem = "Alterações realizadas com sucesso!";
        }
        alert(mensagem);
    </script>
';
```

**Pode fazer assim também**

```
echo '
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja alterar o cadastro ?")) {            
            alert ("Alterações realizadas com sucesso!");            
        } else {
            alert ("Alterações descartadas!");            
        }
    </script>
';
```

O erro do seu confirm() está na parte onde você coloca as chaves após o função confirm() como se ela fosse um operador relacional, onde na verdade é para colocar ele dentro do operador de decisão if(), pois de acordo com a sua escolha a função retorna TRUE ou FALSE. Não precisa do break no final do alert.

```
echo '
    <script type="text/JavaScript"> 
        confirm("Tem certeza que deseja alterar o cadastro ?"); 
        **{**        
            if (false) {
              alert("Alterações descartadas !").break;
            }
            
            else {
              alert("Alterações realizadas com sucesso !");
            }
        **}** 
    </script>
';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo ! Sei que existem muitos erros nesse meu código, mas de fato não é um trabalho comercial, não vou nem chegar a colocar no ar esse sistema, estou fazendo mesmo como estudo, como aprendizado, e muito obrigado pelo aprendizado, estou em fase de estudo e toda e qualquer informação é de extrema importância no meu caso que ainda estou em 0,1% de evolução em programação geral, mas conheço um pouco sobre cada linguagem (HTML, PHP, CSS, JAVA e SQL).